# Moodle File API uploading an image

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I am currently working on Moodle and i am trying to upload an image and display it.

I followed all the steps explained here : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#Simple_use
and it is working.

For example if i upload a file with some text in it and i access the URL given by the make_pluginfile_url function it will display the text that is inside the file.

The problem is when i upload an image it doesn't display the image but some text like this :

```
(+�ء��\U�k���*�j~�Uܽ�U���W\Uت�k��zb��S�
```

I suppose it's because the File API treats the image as a text file and not as an .jpg.

Could someone tell me how i could make it display the image ?

Comment: I don't know why but it works now ... I didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Display it with html_writer class. Example:

html_writer::empty_tag('img', array('src'=> $url));
Where $url is valid url to your file. (Prepared with moodle_url::make_pluginfile_url() or similar)

[empty_tag docs](https://fossies.org/dox/moodle-3.2.3/classhtml__writer.html#ac0aa2959ef74411225e034c2e171e879)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, i tried to display it with html_writer like you said but it doesn't seem to work. It displays the broken image logo.

Comment: then check if url generated for your image is correct. If you paste is into your browser it should take you to this image. Pattern of such url would look something like this: yoursite.com/pluginfile.php/contextid/component/filearea/filename.jpg

Comment: Yeah i already did it, my url is genereted with make_pluginfile_url() but when i go to the page it displays some strange text like this : (+�ء��\U�k���*�j~�Uܽ�U���W\Uت�k��zb��S�